# Program won't continue when pressing enter. How do I fix this error?

Tags: java, indexing

I am working on a rock paper scissors homework assignment for my java class. I am done with the program and I compiled it successfully. I ran the file and it looked like it was working. It gives me the menu and I choose a variable, R for example, and when I press enter it doesn't do anything but go to the next line. I press enter again and it gives me an index out of bounds error which I assume is because the second time it didn't have a variable to use. How do I get the program to move forward? The program is supposed to play five times then return a winner. Thanks in advance.[This image is what I get when I run the program and press enter twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXvNU.png)

```
package Rock;
import java.util.Scanner;




public class RPSG {




public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] computerHandArray = {"R","P","S"};
    String computerHand ="", thisWinner="", theFinalWinner="";
    int index=0;
    int timesIWon=0;
    int timesComputerWon=0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\tMenu\n\n(R) Rock\n(P) Paper\n(S) Scissors" + "\n\nEnter Your Hand (R, P, or S): ");
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        String myHandString = in.nextLine();
        String myHand = myHandString.substring(0,1);
        myHand = myHand.toUpperCase();
        index = (int)(Math.random() * 10) % 3;
        computerHand = computerHandArray[index];
        thisWinner = theWinnerofOneGame(myHand, computerHand);

        if(thisWinner.equals("ME")){
            timesIWon++;
        }
            else if(thisWinner.equals("COMPUTER")) {
                timesComputerWon++;
        }
    }

        if(timesIWon == timesComputerWon)
        theFinalWinner = "TIE";
    else if(timesIWon > timesComputerWon)
            theFinalWinner = "ME";
    else if(timesComputerWon > timesIWon)
        theFinalWinner = "COMPUTER";
    System.out.println("I won :" + timesIWon);
    System.out.println("I won :" + timesComputerWon);
    System.out.println("The Final Winner after 5 games is:" +theFinalWinner);
    }
private static String theWinnerofOneGame(String myHand, String computerHand){
    String theWinner = "Tie";
    if(myHand.equals(computerHand)) {
        theWinner = "Tie"; 
}
    else if(myHand.equals("R")) {
        if (computerHand.equals("P")) {
            theWinner = "COMPUTER";
        }
    }

    else if(computerHand.equals("S")) {
        theWinner = "ME";
    }

else if(myHand.equals("P")) {
    if (computerHand.equals("R")) {
        theWinner = "ME";
    }
    else if(computerHand.equals("S")) {
        theWinner = "COMPUTER";
        }
    }
else if(myHand.equals("S")) {
    if (computerHand.equals("R")) {
        theWinner = "COMPUTER";

    }

    else if(computerHand.equals("P")) {
        theWinner = "ME";
    }
}
    return theWinner;
    }

}
```

Comment: Just a little note I saw for System.out.println("I won :" + timesComputerWon); make sure ya swap it to Computer won: or something in the print.

Answer (score 3):

You print the prompt for input only once, i.e. before the `for` loop. Now when you enter your first input, the content of the loop will be executed. Because you don't print anything inside the loop, there is no prompt for the next round. After you press enter a second time, the `in.nextLine()` returns an empty string and subsequently, the `substring` method throws the exception.

You should probably do something like this (note the marked lines):

```java
System.out.println("\tMenu\n\n(R) Rock\n(P) Paper\n(S) Scissors" + "\n\n");
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
>        System.out.println("Enter Your Hand (R, P, or S): ");
        String myHandString = in.nextLine();
        String myHand = myHandString.substring(0,1);
        myHand = myHand.toUpperCase();
        index = (int)(Math.random() * 10) % 3;
        computerHand = computerHandArray[index];
        thisWinner = theWinnerofOneGame(myHand, computerHand);

        if(thisWinner.equals("ME")){
            timesIWon++;
>            System.out.println("You won.");
        } else if(thisWinner.equals("COMPUTER")) {
            timesComputerWon++;
>            System.out.println("The computer won.");
        }
    }
```

And even better, check if the input of the user is valid before computing the substring.